# Shape en android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

bendiciones a todos. estoy necesitando hacer medio circulo, si asi como lees, medio circulo con un shape en xml, para situarlo en un fragment escrito en kotlin.

```
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#a382ef"/>
        <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"></size>
    </shape>
 </item>
```

este codigo es del circulo completo y llamado desde un imageview. mi intencion es mostrar medio circulo. gracias

Comment: Agrega el shape que has tratado, tal vez necesite solo una pequeña modificación, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: gracias jorge en seguida edito la pregunta.

Comment: muchas gracias a ti por editar tu pregunta, agregué una respuesta de acuerdo a lo que trataste, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#a382ef" />
    <size
        android:height="120dp"
        android:width="60dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="60dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Se puede variar el valor de `size` y `corners` para obtener diferentes orientaciones del círculo como en el ejemplo de @Jorgesys.

Answer (score 3):

Tu imagen originalmente se mostraría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#a382ef"/>
    <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"></size>
</shape>
```

si de seas medio circulo puedes usar un rectangle definiendo `android:bottomRightRadius` y `android:bottomLeftRadius` del doble del ancho para definir la curvatura, obviamente una altura de la mitad del ancho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#a382ef"/>
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="240dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="240dp"/>
</shape>
```